# Java - Cannot instantiate the type One2OneChannel

Tags: java, instantiation

When trying to start a very simple program I am getting the error "Cannot instantiate the type One2OneChannel" on line 6.

```
import org.jcsp.lang.*;

public class main {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    One2OneChannel chan = new One2OneChannel();
}
```

I have seen in other programs such as the one here http://www.di.unipi.it/didadoc/labIII/ONLINE/jcsp-docs/jcsp/plugNplay/Merge.html people have successfully created new One2OneChannels with the same code I am trying to use.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Have you checked out this documentation. According to this One2OneChannel is of type interface, not a class. [Link](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/jcsp-1.1-rc4/jcsp-doc/org/jcsp/lang/One2OneChannel.html)

Comment: http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/jcsp1-0-rc7/jcsp-docs/jcsp/lang/One2OneChannel.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically it's because the constructor of the class has been set to private / protected -- or the type is an Interface, not a class. According to this documentation: http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/jcsp-1.1-rc4/jcsp-doc/org/jcsp/lang/Channel.html you can create One2OneChannel by following code:

```
One2OneChannel channel = Channel.createOne2One();
```

Comment: i get the error "The method createOne2One() from the type Channel is deprecated"

Comment: nevermind it still compiles and works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [class](http://www.di.unipi.it/didadoc/labIII/ONLINE/jcsp-docs/jcsp/lang/One2OneChannel.html) you're trying to instantiate belongs to `jcsp.lang` package. You need to modify the import statement accordingly.

Comment: i get the error message "The import jcsp cannot be resolved" if I import jcsp.lang.* not org.jcsp.lang.*

Comment: The examples you're pointing to in your question are using `import jcsp.lang.*;`. Are you sure you're using the right version of the API?